# How to convert string to object and counting number?

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, object

my current string :
var a = aaa,2;bbb,1;ccc,3

my expectation result with count number after delimeter :
var a = 6 (from count 2+1+3)

Comment: Could you share the code which assigns value to `var a` and add the code you tried for this question. From that we could help you resolving the same.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I think this is want you want:

```js
var a = "aaa,2;bbb,1;ccc,3";

let result = a.split(";").map(e=>e.split(",")[1]).map(e=>Number(e)).reduce((a,e)=>a+e,0);

console.log(result)
```

Comment: Your question is not that clear so my first answer was wrong. But now that i've edited i think this is what you want